# How can I fix a java code that has no class

Tags: java

I am trying to correct the error in fix 5 below. It asks for the logical error and to correct it. I think the logical error is that there is no cheese class, but how would I edit the code so that the logical error is fix? I am not sure how to add the class needed in the code and if its needed though?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab21_Vars {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i, j;
        int var0, var1;

        // Fix 1: Correctly typecast 5.0 to an int so it can assigned to var3.
        int var2 = 0, var3 = (int) 5.0;
        //int var2 = 0, var3 = 5.0;

        // Fix 2: Correctly declare a variable as an array.
        int [] arri0 = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
        //int arri0 = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

        double[] arrd0 = {0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};

        // Fix 3: What's wrong with temp? Fix it.
        int temp = 0;

        if (i < j) {
            //int temp = 0; 
            System.out.println("Temp is " + temp);
        } else {
            temp = 1;
            System.out.println("Temp is " + temp);
        }

        // Fix 4: Correctly calculate square of sums and print it as total.
        int total = 0; 

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            //int total = 0;
            total += i*i;
        }
        System.out.println("i value is " + i);
        System.out.println("Total is " + total);


        // Fix 5: Figure out the logical error and correct it.

        Cheese jack;
        Cheese monterey = new Cheese("Monterey");
        jack = monterey;
        System.out.println("Monterey name is " + monterey.getName());
        jack.setName("Jack");
        System.out.println("Jack name is " + jack.getName());
        System.out.println("Monterey name is still " + monterey.getName());

        // Fix 6: Make the following code shorter by combining redundant 
        //        (unnecessary/duplicate) statements

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
        int num1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
        int num2 = input.nextInt();

        if (num1 > var3) 
            System.out.println("First is greater");
        else
            System.out.println("First is Less than or equal");

        if (num2 < var3)
            System.out.println("Second is Less than");
        else
            System.out.println("Second is Greater or equal");

        /*
        if (input.nextInt() > var3) {
            System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
            int num2 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("First is greater");
            if (num2 < var3)
                System.out.println("Second is Less than");
            else
                System.out.println("Second is Greater or equal");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
            int num2 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("First is Less than or equal");
            if (num2 < var3)
                System.out.println("Second is Less than");
            else
                System.out.println("Second is Greater or equal");
        }
         */

        // Fix 7: Print out the first number entered by the user
        //        (Hint - You will need to modify the above code)
        System.out.println("The first number was " + num1);
    }
    }
```

Comment: If you can't see the issue with Fix 5, let me ask you a question: What do you think `jack = monterey;` does, and why do you think that?

Answer (score 1):

```
Cheese jack;
Cheese monterey = new Cheese("Monterey");
jack = monterey;
System.out.println("Monterey name is " + monterey.getName());
jack.setName("Jack");
System.out.println("Jack name is " + jack.getName());
System.out.println("Monterey name is still " + monterey.getName());
```

No, the absence of the `Cheese` class is hardly the intended logical error here. A logical error would refer to the *logic* in this code, whether it behaves correctly when run, not to a compile error from `Cheese` not referring to any existing class (preventing you from running the code at all).

So you will need to assume that there is a `Cheese` class and that a cheese has a name that you can get and set.

The code seems to assume that the last statement will print

> Monterey name is still Monterey

With a standard behaviour of `setName()` and `getName()` this will however not be the case. So your job is to find out why it prints something else and presumably how to fix the code to get the above output.

I am happily and confidently leaving that to you. :-)